# How to start developing with OpenGL and C++, what tools do I need to install on windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I am inspired to start programming some things in OpenGL, using c++.

Can anyone list here what tools should be installed to start this process.

Ie

IDE
Compiler
OpenGL download etc?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Ne-He tutorials (to which @wich has already kindly provided a link) are quite good for what they are (but at least the last time I looked carefully, the OpenGL the teach and work with is quite dated).

glut, however, I'd generally avoid. It has a fair number of bugs, and nobody's working on fixing them. It was basically abandoned in a beta test state in the late 1990s, so it seems doubtful (at best) that anybody will ever even try to fix them.

A couple of alternatives to glut (both apparently in active development) are [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) and [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/). Between these, GLFW is much closer to glut in character -- a small toolkit for abstracting away most of the OS-dependent parts, so you can produce OpenGL programs with relatively little hassle. FLTK is really a full-blown GUI toolkit (though rather small as GUI toolkits go) that has a built-in glut emulation (that, at least the last time I played with it, seemed considerably better implemented than glut itself).

I suppose I should also point out one more alternative to glut: [freeglut](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeglut/) is a free re-implementation of the glut API. I can't say I really recommend it, but at least it's been actively developed a lot more recently than the original glut.

When/if you decide you want to play around with shaders, both [AMD](https://gpuopen.com/) and [nVidia](http://developer.nvidia.com/page/home.html) have developer web pages. nVidia's, in particular, has a huge amount of free "stuff" available (just beware that it's easy to burn all too many hours playing around with their demos and such).

Comment: +1 for FLTK. I'm goingto have to check that out now.

Comment: (advice) do not put too much hope onto GLFW, it has its amount of bugs, which may become a showstopper if you try to approach something ambitious with; for prototyping though, it may be the best choice

Answer (score 4):

The following three IDEs are very usable, and can all be used for c++ OpenGL development. Qt is more of a cross platform framework, but all can be used to develop glut based OpenGL apps.

- [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP)
- [QT Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/)
- [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

Answer (score 3):

No special OpenGL-specific compiler or IDE should be needed. All you need is a C++ compiler. VisualStudio Express Edition C++ should be able to do it. You can also go with NetBeans or Eclipse, both of which have C++ editions now. They may also have OpenGL plugins, specifically, I recall hearing about a GLSL shaders plugin for NetBeans (but that was a while ago, so that info may be out of date). Don't forget to check out the [OpenGL SDK page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/), which also has some good tools and references.

The main OpenGL site is also a good resrouce to start with: http://www.opengl.org/
(and someone else mentioned the [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) - they're also great!)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my piece of (a former OpenGL toyer's) advice on the choice of libraries and tools (as for the compiler, you can just use any free modern one out there (i.e., gcc or VSExpress C++)):

1. Do not forget to look at [GLEW (The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library)](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLee (GL Easy Extension library)](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/), especially if you'd like to be stick with more modern OpenGL features (including advanced shaders).
2. Something named like [Shader Debugger](http://www.google.com/search?hl=ru&newwindow=1&q=shader+debugger&btnG=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&lr=&aq=f&oq=) will probably also be of great benefit when toying with shaders, as it will give the opportunity to see shader effect immediately without even compiling any C/C++ sources.
3. Looking at the "traditional" (covered in the (free now) "Red book") functionality from the modern (i.e. shaders again:)) viewpoint may also be enlightening, the ["Orange book" ("OpenGL Shading Language (3rd Edition))"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637631) has a chapter on emulating OpenGL fixed functionality with shaders.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [NeonHelium OpenGL tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/)

Answer (score 0):

CodeBlocks + GLUT:

http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~goetz/codeblocks/glut/

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from GLUT it is a crutch at best, you really need to learn how to use the OpenGL Api's directly to do high performance graphics. Also alot of the NeHe tutorials are old and outdated. There are lots of new Api's for the newer graphics cards that those tutorials don't cover.

Comment: What's in GLUT that will prevent him from using the OpenGL API directly? Also, I think it will be important for the OP to learn the fundamentals of OpenGL before he learns the "new APIs".

Comment: The Ne-He tutorials certainly aren't the be-all and end-all, but I think they're a reasonable *starting* point for somebody with no OpenGL experience at all.