# GLSL shader loader problem

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

The problem is that my glsl loader does not work and i dont see what im doing wrong.

```
void cShader::Load(const char *v_filename,const char *f_filename)
{
  char *vs,*fs;

  vShaderList = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  fShaderList = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); 

  std::ifstream v_fs;
  v_fs.open(v_filename,std::ios::binary);
  v_fs.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
  int v_filesize = v_fs.tellg();
  vs = new char[v_filesize+1];
  v_fs.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
  v_fs.read(vs,v_filesize);
  v_fs.close();
  vs[v_filesize] = '\n';
  std::cout.write(vs,v_filesize);

  std::ifstream f_fs;
  f_fs.open(f_filename,std::ios::binary);
  f_fs.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
  int f_filesize = f_fs.tellg();
  fs = new char[f_filesize+1];
  f_fs.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
  f_fs.read(fs,f_filesize);
  f_fs.close();
  fs[f_filesize] = '\n';
  std::cout.write(fs,f_filesize);
  const char * vv = vs;
  const char * ff = fs;

  glShaderSource(vShaderList, 1, &vv,NULL);
  glShaderSource(fShaderList, 1, &ff,NULL);

  free(vs);free(fs);

  glCompileShader(vShaderList);
  glCompileShader(fShaderList);

  ShaderID = glCreateProgram();

  glAttachShader(ShaderID,vShaderList);
  glAttachShader(ShaderID,fShaderList);

  glLinkProgram(ShaderID);
  glUseProgram(ShaderID);
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should answer is: What does not work? It crashes? You gte a blank screen? Etc.

Comment: ah it was the vertex shader file that was wrong(i copy one with errors). sorry.

Comment: vs = new char[...]; [...] free(vs); 

You're really asking for trouble. use delete [] vs;

Answer (score 3):

You could use `glGetShaderiv` and `glGetShaderInfoLog` to get some idea of what it thinks is going wrong. I posted some (tested, working) sample code in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795044/easy-framework-for-opengl-shaders-in-c-c/2796153#2796153) to a previous question.