# C++ shader question

Tags: c++, templates, boost, shader

Does somebody know where I can find a sample of shader (HLSL / CG / GLSL / Backend-independent) class?

*Of course, standard API (like `D3DXEffect` or same in `GL`) exists, but it's kind of ugly and not what I'm looking for.*

*I'm looking for a high-quality interface design, not **"just yet another implementation sample"***.

Ideally something ideologically close to `boost::` template-based library and "suitable" for different usage cases.

If someone met something similiar (OK if it's not finished, I'm just going to grab the idea and reimplement it myself). If you have any ideas on **a shader** concept design, this is also appreciated.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to re-implement shaders on your own, or whether you want code that load/use shaders. Assuming the latter, you might want to look at the code I posted in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795044/easy-framework-for-opengl-shaders-in-c-c/2796153#2796153). I've found it quite useful (and pretty easy to use).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a shading language virtual machine for a ray-tracer. Mainly I developed it to support basic operations that are usually done over un-textured surfaces but I don't think it's enough for you.. You can dowload the manual of my language [here](http://jacoposantoni.com/shady-manual.pdf).

If you think you are interested I can give you the code (written in C/C++) or some hints..