# What is the most short way to run your GLSL shader (not compiled yet) from C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, glsl

So what is simple - crossplatform C++ library for compiling and running GLSL shaders from source  and emulating videocard if needed. Generally I want to give it shader and data and be capable to run it and get resulting data. Is there any such library/ or described way to use some libs in combo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to use a cross-platform OpenGL framework like [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) with a bit to compile and use a shader (e.g., one I posted in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795044/easy-framework-for-opengl-shaders-in-c-c/2796153#2796153)). For systems that didn't support OpenGL otherwise, you'd probably want to use [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/).

Comment: Is there any need in precompiling shaders in Mesa3d? And Can you please provide any code example similar (or even better same) as one you provided for GLFW?

Comment: @Blender: Mesa3d would be used along with the other parts -- i.e., you'd write your code using GLFW, and it would (implicitly) use Mesa3D as the implementation of OpenGL. You just write OpenGL code, and Mesa3D can be used to provide an OpenGL implementation on a system that doesn't have one otherwise.