# Reading file, corrupted data

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glsl, glfw

It seems I can't have my **GLSL shaders** compiled. Once in a while (mainly after editing a file), I get following error while compiling:

```
----- SRC ----- (150 B)
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

in vec4 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vertexPosition_modelspace;
}
gp!
----- END -----
SimpleTransform.vertexshader:Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:10: error(#132) Syntax error: 'gp' parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

It's quite strange since I swear the file doesn't contain that awkward `gp!` part. Nevertheless I investigated it with *cat*

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

in vec4 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vertexPosition_modelspace;
}
```

and *less*

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

in vec4 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vertexPosition_modelspace;
}
```

and both of them proved me right.

I wonder what's causing this strange behaviour.

Here's link to [my project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90959340/project.tar.xz). You should be able to easily compile it by entering *src* directory and typing `make` (*Linux* only). It requires GLFW, GLEW, GLM and GL3.

And the code itself:

Loading shader files

```
GLuint shader_load(GLenum type, const char filename[]) {
    if ((type != GL_VERTEX_SHADER && type != GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER) || !filename) return 0;

    /* wczytywanie pliku shadera */
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb"); 

    //okreslenie rozmiaru pliku
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);   
    uint32 iFileSize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //wczytywanie
    char *tmp = new char[iFileSize];
    memset(tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));
    uint32 iBytes = (uint32) fread(tmp, sizeof(char), iFileSize, file); 
    fclose(file);   
    if (iBytes != iFileSize) printf("Warning: reading error possible!\n");

    #ifdef _DEBUG_
    printf("----- SRC ----- (%d B)\n%s\n----- END -----\n", iBytes, tmp);
    #endif

    /* przygotowanie shadera */
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, const_cast<const GLchar**>(&tmp), NULL);
    delete[] tmp;
    glCompileShader(shader); //kompilacja shadera

    /* sprawdzenie statusu kompilacji */
    int status = GL_FALSE; 
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);  
    int logsize = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logsize);
    char *log = new char[logsize];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logsize, NULL, log);
    printf("%s:%s", filename, log);         
    delete[] log;
    if (status != GL_TRUE)  return 0;

    return shader;
}
```

Comment: Please show your relevant code here, you'll get a better response than waiting for someone to download and dig through your project. I'll guess there's some issue with not null-terminating the shader strings.

Comment: Don't send me your project to build it using some complicated platform-dependent build procedure. Just post the relevant code (most probably the shader loading code). That will last even once you removed your project and the link went dead next week.

Comment: @ChristianRau added *loading shader* source code

Comment: Also, if you use gDEBugger you can see what code actually gets sent to the graphics card for each shader. (Not all graphics drivers will show the shader source code when reporting error messages)

Comment: [Added a sample snippet that shows how the fragment would have been written using `std::string`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12117852/85371) instead of juggling raw arrays, `memset`, off-by-ones and hairy casts :)

Comment: I'd start from the classes I posted in an [earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2796153/179910), and add code to read data from a file and pass it through to be compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **FIRST OFF** Switch to C++ instead of C-with-a-cpp extension to avoid shipwrecks like this.

Analysis:

---

Running under valgrind shows

```
==15579== Invalid read of size 1
==15579==    at 0x5B95C65: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1623)
==15579==    by 0x5B9E768: printf (printf.c:35)
==15579==    by 0x4019C1: shader_load(unsigned int, char const*) (shaders.cpp:88)
==15579==    by 0x401B30: program_create(char const*, char const*) (shaders.cpp:120)
==15579==    by 0x401D65: main (in /tmp/ogl-jg-3/test)
==15579==  Address 0xb3018a6 is 0 bytes after a block of size 150 alloc'd
==15579==    at 0x4C2864B: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==15579==    by 0x401961: shader_load(unsigned int, char const*) (shaders.cpp:81)
==15579==    by 0x401B30: program_create(char const*, char const*) (shaders.cpp:120)
==15579==    by 0x401D65: main (in /tmp/ogl-jg-3/test)
```

It tells you exactly that it tries to read beyond the end of the buffer `tmp` which is allocated in line 81. It seems you are somehow assuming it is null-terminated. Which it isn't. Add that:

```
//wczytywanie
char *tmp = new char[iFileSize+1];
memset(tmp, 0, (iFileSize+1)*sizeof(char));
uint32 iBytes = (uint32) fread(tmp, sizeof(char), iFileSize, file); 
fclose(file);   
if (iBytes != iFileSize) printf("Warning: reading error possible!\n");

#ifdef _DEBUG_
    printf("----- SRC ----- (%d B)\n%s\n----- END -----\n", iBytes, tmp);
#endif
```

And I get semi-decent output. The GL window stays blank, though

### **Update**

To make it clearer what I meant by ***switch to C++*** here's the idea:

```
GLuint shader_load(GLenum type, const char filename[]) {
    if ((type != GL_VERTEX_SHADER && type != GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER) || !filename) return 0;

    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
    std::string src;
    {
        /* wczytywanie pliku shadera */
        std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
        if (!std::getline(ifs, src, '\0'))
            std::cerr << "Warning: reading error possible!\n";
    }

#ifdef _DEBUG_
    std::cout << "----- SRC ----- " << src.size() << " B \n" << src << "\n----- END -----\n";
#endif

    /* przygotowanie shadera */
    const GLchar* sources[] = { src.c_str() };
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, sources, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader); //kompilacja shadera
```

Comment: Or, you could just pass the string length to glShaderSource in the 4th parameter, which is an array to integers holding the length's of the strings pointed to in the array elements in the 3rd parameter.

Comment: @datenwolf I would never have known, because I don't do graphics programming, and don't know the APIs :) Thanks for the useful note

Comment: While you switched to C++, why then use C files and the like and not just do a simple `std::istream file(filename); std::string tmp(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), (std::istreambuf_iterator()));` instead of the whole `fread` and `resize` mess (not speak of an explicit `fclose`)? Your code isn't really any less C/C++ than his.

Comment: @ChristianRau Mostly because (a) it wasn't related to the question (b) it wasn't related to the answer (c) it wasn't my problem. But since you have a fair point, ***I updated the answer for it*** :)

Comment: @sehe I agree that it wasn't your problem and neither related to the question, but since you explicitly suggest him to switch from C/C++ to proper C++, it was pretty relevant for the answer.

Comment: Are you sure the file contains a `0` at the end?

Comment: @ChristianRau Huh? I'm sure that reading will stop at the end of the file, if that's what you mean :) I'm also sure that embedded NUL characters cannot (meaningfully) occur, as they would have terminated the source (strlen is called on it, as valgrind told me). Sooooooo.... _Pretty safe_. A lot safer, and shorter, than the original, I'd say

Comment: @sehe Yeah indeed, you're right, of course `getline` stops at the end and NUL is probably not in there otherwise, makes sense.