# OpenGL VBO, VAO, Cubes, and Colors

Tags: opengl, colors, cube, vbo

I'm currently trying to get my head around VBOs and I'm running into some problems.

I'm using an interleaved array with position, colors, and normals. However, when I go to draw, the display is just white.

This is the structure of my array:

```
GLfloat position[3];
GLfloat normal[3];
GLfloat color[4];
```

Here's the code:

**Initialization:**

```
glGenBuffers(1, &arrays[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, arrays[0]);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 125*10*36*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID[1]);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID[1]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vaoID[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 40, ((void*)0));
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 40, ((void*)12));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 40, ((void*)24));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

**Draw:**

```
glPushMatrix();
glBindVertexArray(vaoID[1]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 125*36);
glPopMatrix();
```

I'm making a 5x5 cube of cubes that spectrum in color from black to white. However, on draw, this is all I'm getting:

[image: White Cube.]

Comment: You didn't show shaders. Also, `glPush/PopMatrix` is deprecated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the shaders? I'm currently doing:


 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
 glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
 glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

which was working to color the cubes in immediate mode.

Comment: Well, you didn't post your shader code. Are you using any?

Comment: Nope. I'm new to this. Do I need to use shaders for VBOs? Or can I define the colors in the arrays and be done with it there?

Comment: As you can see, these are general vertex attributes. I believe there was some sort of default binding to colors, but it's driver-dependent, I believe. It would be easier to just write trivial vertex and fragment shaders. http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut

Comment: I added a simple pass-through shader with the help of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2796153c) but I'm still getting no color.

I haven't changed anything else other than adding in the shader run into every draw call.

Comment: Well, now push the vertex color attribute from vertex shader to fragment shader.

Answer (score 2):

I see a problem with what you've posted above. You've defined your colors as being floats in the struct, but you're telling `glVertexAttribPointer()` that your colors are unsigned bytes. It should probably be something like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 40, ((void*)24));
```

And that assumes that you're actually putting floats into those memory locations. How are you setting them?

Comment: I changed it from GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE to GL_FLOAT and I'm still only getting a white cube. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1118321 How would he possibly get the attribute index of the color attribute without shaders? I don't think this is defined anywhere in OpenGL

Comment: @fscan You're probably right - I was thinking of legacy OpenGL in immediate mode. I've removed that line from my response. I believe the rest of the response is valid, though.